# Поиск на PHP

Tags: база-данных, php, sql

Делаю поиск на РНР, но не получается. Вылазит ошибка

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Код:

```
$news = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE MATCH (name, text1, text2) AGAINST (`$search` IN BOOLEAN MODE)",$connect);
$rownews = mysql_fetch_array($news);
```

Структура:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
`id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`cat` int(4) NOT NULL,
`rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
`img` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`text1` text NOT NULL,
`text2` text NOT NULL,
`date` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FULLTEXT KEY `text2` (`text2`),
FULLTEXT KEY `text1` (`text1`),
FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в кавычках, правильнее

```
$news = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE MATCH (name, text1, text2) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)",$connect);
if (is_bool($news)) { // или можно $news === FALSE
    die "Mysql (".mysql_errno($connect).") ".mysql_error($connect)."\n";
}
else {
    $rownews = mysql_fetch_array($news);
    // Что там нужно будет делать дальше
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` возвращает `FALSE` в случае ошибки. А вы этот `FALSE` передаете в `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Найдите ошибку в запросе и добавьте проверку на `FALSE` перед `mysql_fetch_array`

Answer (score 0):

Просто напишите перед запросом: echo mysql_error();
там всё покажет

Answer (score 0):

Убери из запроса `WHERE`, мне по крайней мере помогло!

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MATCH (search) AGAINST ('XXX' IN BOOLEAN MODE)' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

После AGAINST круглые скобки тебе зачем. Убери.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MATCH (name, text1, text2) AGAINST 'xxx' IN BOOLEAN MODE' at line 1


Согласно доке http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match скобки обязятельны